# Mavericks Dock icons have become corrupted. Is there a cache to flush or a database to rebuild?

Tags: macos, dock, icon

I'm running OS X Mavericks 10.9.1. Some of my Dock icons for running applications, including the Finder icon, now appear blank and empty, or as a square filled with random noise pixels.

I have tried "Verify Disk" in Recovery mode, and it detects no errors. I have Repaired Permissions and rebooted.

Is there some cache to flush or database to rebuild that could fix this seemingly harmless but annoying anomaly?

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to use some "cache cleaner app" then just try doing it manually from the terminal with these three commands followed by a reboot:

`sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;`

`sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rf {} \;`

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store`

#### or

Alternatively [a single boot into Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25617) once could/should clear out some caches.

*Worked For Me™* in Sierra (10.12)

Answer (score 0):

I used a utility (CleanMyMac 2) to flush all the User and System cache files, and when I rebooted, the problem seems to have been solved.

So I don't know which specific cache needed flushing, but everything looks good now.

And yes, I could have done this with Terminal commands, but I prefer to use something with a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Wheat,

If it was my Mac I'd start by clearing all the caches with [AppleJack](http://applejack.sourceforge.net/). This is a great utility for this sort of task.